# Sort elements to specified data-* order

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a list of items in a `<ul>`:

```
<li data-number="1"> Pierce </li>
<li data-number="2"> Annie </li>
<li data-number="3"> Jeff </li>
<li data-number="4"> Abed </li>
<li data-number="5"> Britta </li>
```

Actually, the list is much longer with real data, but bear with me. As you can see, the `<li>` elements are listed in numerical order. However, I need to rearrange them to fit a specified order in an array:

```
Array(2, 3, 1, 5, 4)
```

How do I do this? If sorted by the array above, the elements should be like the following:

```
<li data-number="2"> Annie </li>
<li data-number="3"> Jeff </li>
<li data-number="1"> Pierce </li>
<li data-number="5"> Britta </li>
<li data-number="4"> Abed </li>
```

This seems simple, but I've looked up every jQuery method in the book and I can't figure out how to do this. Thanks a ton for any help in advance.

#### Further Clarification:

The specified order is dynamic. However, the elements are always initially listed in numerical order.

Comment: Is the order pattern always defined or is it dynamic?

Comment: The specified order pattern (`2, 3, 1, 5, 4`) changes all the time. However, the elements are always initially listed in numerical order, as shown in the first example.

Comment: Okay, supplied an answer. Give that a shot.

Comment: ¿Donde esta la biblioteca? But where are Troy and Shirley?

Comment: @nnnnnn Hahaha, so glad someone got the reference!

Comment: Wanted to fit them in, but couldn't as I wanted to keep it to 5 `<li>` elements. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the array starting at index 1. Then append that item after its preceding element. That's it.

http://jsfiddle.net/jT8Tt/

```
var order = [2, 3, 1, 5, 4];

for (var i = 1; i < order.length; i++) {
    $('li[data-number="' + order[i] + '"]').insertAfter($('li[data-number="' + order[i - 1] + '"]'));
}
```

Or in slightly more readable format

```
for (var i = 1; i < order.length; i++) {
    var curElem = $('li[data-number="' + order[i] + '"]');
    var prevElem = $('li[data-number="' + order[i - 1] + '"]');
    curElem.insertAfter(prevElem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a bit rough since I'm not sure of your overall process but I'll give you the gist and you can implement it.

If the key is predefined...

```
var sort_order = ['2', '3', '1', '5', '4']
$.each(sort_order function(key,value){

   // build you list here you can use the value from your sort_order
  // to match the data-number and print them out in the order of your choosing.
  // this will work if you dynamically create the sort_order as well.
});
```

The $.each function will work through the sort_order array allowing you to define an order.

Comment: Right... but as I iterate through the array using `$.each`, how do I move the `<li>` elements to the correct positions? Is there some way with jQuery that I can say, move `$("li[data-name=3]")` to the 3rd place in the DOM?

Comment: Are they already pre-rendered? Or is this done before page display?

Comment: The `<li>` elements are part of the HTML loaded by HTTP, they're not loaded in by Javascript. (You don't need to use `jQuery.live()` if that's what you mean)

Comment: You can use $("ul").append("<li data-number="+value+"></li>"); to append li's in the right order. But again I don't know how you're getting your <li>'s created in the first place.

Comment: I understand that.. You've supplied very little code. I don't know if this is in a fucntion that is called after the page is loaded and needs to repopulate the <ul> or if this is the first population of the <ul> element.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I'd already written this so it seems a shame to waste it:

```
var newOrder = ['2', '3', '1', '5', '4'],
    $ul = $("ul"),
    $lis = $ul.children().remove();

$.each(newOrder, function(key,val){
    $ul.append($lis.filter('[data-number="' + val+ '"]'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zgD3n/

Comment: Thank you very much! Interesting method, I think I'll use that.